# Pandas read_csv: decimal and delimiter is the same character

Tags: python, pandas, csv, plot

Recently I'm struggling to read an csv file with pandas pd.read_csv.
The problem is, that in the csv file a comma is used both as decimal point and as separator for columns.
The csv looks as follows:

```
wavelength,intensity
390,0,382
390,1,390
390,2,400
390,3,408
390,4,418
390,5,427
390,6,437
390,7,447
390,8,457
390,9,468
```

Pandas accordingly always splits the data into three separate columns. However the first comma is only the decimal point.
I want to plot it with the wavelength (x-axis) with **390.0**, **390.1**, **390.2** nm and so on.

I must somehow tell pandas, that the first comma in line is the decimal point, and the second one is the separator.
How do I do this?

Best

Comment: That problem is impossible to solve.  You need to edit the CSV file, either to change the decimal to a dot, or to change the delimiter to something else.  Pandas cannot untangle this automatically.  You can certainly read the rows in manually, do the translation your self, and just pass a list of rows to pandas.

Comment: (I removed the first line of your file since I assume it's not relevant and it's distracting.)

Comment: Are those the only two columns in your CSV?

Comment: What's wrong with reading the file as is, then adding column 2 divided by 10 to column 1?

Comment: Yep, these are the only columns in the whole file.
Then I'll guess, I try to sum the first and second column after reading with pandas to get x-data.

Edit: Thanks Ben, thats also what came to my mind. However, I tried to keep it more elegant.

Comment: @Tim want a surprise? Check the bottom of my answer!

Comment: @BigBen ping you also in case you didn't get the comment. Check my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is possible. It *almost* is, as you can see by the following example:

```
>>> pd.read_csv('test.csv', engine='python', sep=r',(?!\d+$)')
   wavelength intensity
0         390     0,382
1         390     1,390
2         390     2,400
3         390     3,408
4         390     4,418
5         390     5,427
6         390     6,437
7         390     7,447
8         390     8,457
9         390     9,468
```

...but the wrong comma is being split. I'll keep trying to see if it's possible ;)

Meanwhile, a simple solution would be to take advantage of the fact that that pandas puts part of the first column in the index:

```
df = (pd.read_csv('test.csv')
    .reset_index()
    .assign(wavelength=lambda x: x['index'].astype(str) + '.' + x['wavelength'].astype(str))
    .drop('index', axis=1)
    .astype({'wavelength': float}))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   wavelength  intensity
0       390.0        382
1       390.1        390
2       390.2        400
3       390.3        408
4       390.4        418
5       390.5        427
6       390.6        437
7       390.7        447
8       390.8        457
9       390.9        468
```

---

EDIT: **It is possible!**

The following regular expression with a little dropna column-wise gets it done:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', engine='python', sep=r',(!?\w+)$').dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  wavelength  intensity
0      390,0        382
1      390,1        390
2      390,2        400
3      390,3        408
4      390,4        418
5      390,5        427
6      390,6        437
7      390,7        447
8      390,8        457
9      390,9        468
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. However, the csv file has way more rows up to 700.0, i just stopped posting at 390.9. The next row is 400,0,470. So taking the index into account does not actually help for the whole file.

Comment: @Dölerich check the bottom of the answer! I just found out a solution that should work for you! :)